# Search Box jQuery Mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, search, append

I am trying to make a search function on my jquery mobile page,

HTML:

```html
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="searchbar" />
    <ul data-role="listview" id="searchlist"></ul>
```

As a user is searching, results will be appended to the listview.

I want the following code to run everytime a letter is typed into the search bar? How do I accomplish this?

```js
    if (searchbar.val().length > 2)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://clubbedin.zymichost.com/search.php",
            type: "post",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                'q': value,
                'userID': userID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i ++)
                {
                    html += '<li><a data-option-id=\"' + json[i].optionid + '\">' + json[i].optionname + '</a></li>';
                }
                $('searchlist').append( html );
                $('searchlist').listview( "refresh" );
            }
        });
     }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keypress` event for this.

```js
$(document).on("keypress", "#searchbar", function (e) { 
 var searchbar = $(this); 
 //your code
});
```

Or you could use `input` event handler. For more info on how to do that refer this link : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile

Basically it would go something like this :

```js
  $(document).on("input", "#searchbar", function (e) { 
   //your code
  });
```

Another way (**and probably the best way**) would be to use jQM inbuilt mechanism to load remote data. [Here's a demo of that. The source code is also provided here.](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.php) Basically you'd be using a `listviewbeforefilter` event to put all the code which calls your `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#searchlist").on("listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
  var $ul = $(this),
  $input = $(data.input),
  value = $input.val(),
  html = ""; 
  if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://clubbedin.zymichost.com/search.php",
        type: "post",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            'q': value,
            'userID': userID
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i ++)
            {
                html += '<li><a data-option-id=\"' + json[i].optionid + '\">' + json[i].optionname + '</a></li>';
            }
            $ul.html(html);
            $ul.listview();
            $ul.listview("refresh");
            $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
        }
    });
  }
});
```